# Ant Design Vue Table rows sorting using drag drop

Tags: sorting, html-table, drag-and-drop, antd, ant-design-vue

I am using Ant Design Vue for my Vue.js project. In the native Ant Design, we have sorting using row drag drop within the table but its not available in Ant Design Vue.

https://www.antdv.com/components/table/

Is there a way to include that feature in Ant Design Vue also?

I tried to use Sortable/Vue.Draggable but its not supporting it.
https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

Thanks